# Retrieving a list of nodes and edges from a specific cluster in igraph

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

Suppose I have the following clusters in a graph:

```
library("igraph")
set.seed(3)
g <- barabasi.game(20, m=2, directed=FALSE)
eb <- cluster_edge_betweenness(g)
plot(eb, g, layout=layout_with_fr)
```

Is it possible to retrieve a list or data frame of the nodes and corresponding edges of the cluster containing the number 5? What about a node that is present in more than one cluster, such as 8 or 14?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
grps <- split(V(g),eb$membership)
grp <- unlist(subset(grps,mapply(`%in%`,5,grps)))
df <- subset(get.data.frame(g),from %in% grp & to %in% grp)
```

such that

```
> df
   from to
9     4  6
16    4 10
17    5 10
34    4 19
35    5 19
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding! Would this code also work if I were to use a clustering algorithm for which the same node was present in multiple clusters, each with distinct edges? Could the df be formatted in such a way as would allow me to discern what connections/edges were part of a single cluster?

Comment: @Abigail575 I think it is possible, but it depends how you represent the overlapped vertices. Assuming `eb` can present overlaps in each group, you you can run ```grp <- subset(grps,mapply(`%in%`,5,grps))
df <- Map(function(x) subset(get.data.frame(g),from %in% x & to %in% x), grp)```. However, as I said, it depends if it is possible to have `5` listed in multiple clusters at the same time

Comment: Hello again @ThomasIsCoding perhaps you can help with a similar question to this? No worries if not. Many thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897539/retrieving-binary-interactions-from-linkcomm-package-as-a-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any method that lets do that automatically. However, you can easily do that by hand.

I am not sure about what you mean by "present in more than one cluster". Cluster membership is mutually exclusive, as you can see from the color of the nodes in the graph, and by the output of the betweenness clustering. There are 6 groups:

```
print(eb)
IGRAPH clustering edge betweenness, groups: 6, mod: 0.26
+ groups:
  $`1`
  [1]  1  2  3 14 15

  $`2`
  [1]  4  5  6 10 19

  $`3`
  [1]  7 11 16

  $`4`
  + ... omitted several groups/vertices

eb$membership
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 6 1 1 3 4 4 2 4

# extract all edges of the graph
d <- igraph::as_data_frame(g, what="edges")

# get membership of interested node
memb <- eb$membership[V(g)==5]
memb
[1] 2

# get all nodes with the same membership
memb_nodes <- V(g)[eb$membership==memb]
memb_nodes
+ 5/20 vertices, from 293a69d:
[1]  4  5  6 10 19

# subset
d <- d[d$from %in% memb_nodes & d$to %in% memb_nodes, ]
d
   from to
9     4  6
16    4 10
17    5 10
34    4 19
35    5 19
```

[image]